# Can't add records in form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

When I am trying to add the new record in the McAccess form, I receive this message:
"The current field must match join key in the table that serves one side of the one-to-many relation. Enter record in one side table with the desired key value then make a record in the desired join key in the many-only table".

The form connected to query which has this "one-to-many" relationship...
But it works in the other databases...
When I add records into table ..it's appears in the form..But not vise versa..

I tried to import this form from almost the same db, still doesn't work...

Please help....!

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what the related table is called? For example, I might have a country table related to my main table with a list of countries and I would not be allowed enter a country that was not on the list. Once you have found the related table, see if you were trying to enter data not in the list and then try data that is in the list.

You can see this from the relationships window:

[image: relationship]

With a form, things might get more complicated. For the most part, you are best using a combobox that allows the user to pick from a list of permitted values.

If you have set up your table to use fields with look-up tables, this is likely to be the first of many problems ( http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm ).